# SOAP call from .net core with Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, soap-client

I am trying to migrate some very old asp.net code to .net core, and there are many calls to a SOAP service.

I can add the connected service fine, but when I try and call it I always get the following response

```
***The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. 
The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="gSOAP Web Service"'.***
```

When I try the same code from a test .net framework project it works fine.

Looking at the traffic via Fiddler, the .net core one is not setting the username and password at all from what I can tell. This is the Fiddler Auth header on the .net core call

```
No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.

Authorization Header is present: Basic Og==
Decoded Username:Password= :
```

Here is the code for the .net core version

```
    var lm = new ListManagerService.lmapiSoapClient();
    lm.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    lm.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
    Console.WriteLine("Current API Version: " + lm.ApiVersion());
```

and here is the same code that works fine on .net framework

```
  var lm = new lmapiSoap.lmapi();
  lm.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
  Console.WriteLine("Current API Version: " + lm.ApiVersion());
```

and the header in Fiddler

```
No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.

Authorization Header is present: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Decoded Username:Password= username:password
```

Now I have found a work around, elsewhere on SO, where you can add a header manually, but that seems to be a lot of work as every call needs to be wrapped in a using statement like this

```
    using (new OperationContextScope(lm.InnerChannel))
    {
        // Add a HTTP Header to an outgoing request
        var auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(lm.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + lm.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        requestMessage.Headers["Authorization"] = auth;
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;
        Console.WriteLine("Current API Version: " + lm.ApiVersion());
    }
```

But there must be an easier way - given how simple this was in all previous versions of .NET

Comment: You can convert the body of that `using` block to a single-line extension method.

Comment: `lm.Credentials` (in your .NET Core code) and `lm.ClientCredentials` (in your .NET Framework code) look like different properties. Please show us what `class lmapiSoapClient` looks like (and you should rename those classes to be `PascalCase`).

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes` <-- This is incorrect. You should not depend on `Default` being some particular encoding but should find out what inner encoding the remote service expects should be used with the `Authorization` header - though as it is SOAP, I imagine you should be using `ISO-8859-1` or `Encoding.ASCII`, as per RFC 7617.

Comment: Do you have access to the `HttpClient` and/or the underlying `HttpClientHandler`? If so, have you tried `PreAuthenticate = true`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.preauthenticate?view=net-6.0

Comment: The HTTP headers are different.  Changing Net version should not affect the headers.  So the issue is the code is different.  You need to compare Apples and Apples.  Saying Apples work and Orange doesn't work doesn't help solve the issue when you are using different versions of Net and different version of code.  You don't know if Net is bad or the Code is bad.

Comment: Credentials and ClientCredentials are generated by Visual Studio when you add a connected service from the UI.  So in .net-core the ClientCredentials do not exist

Also the PreAuthenticate does not exist on the generate .net core version.

.net generate a class of type WebClientProtocol
.net core generate a class of type System.ServiceModel.ChannelBase

So I agree - I am not comparing apples to apples, but I do not know how to get apples in .net core

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The "Add connected service" codegen in VS leaves a lot to be desired. There are alternatives, such as using the design-time generated client-assemblies from older versions of VS and disassembling them and then recompiling them for .NET Core 3.1+, alternatively, have you considered just writing `HttpClient` extensions for SOAP actions by-hand?

Comment: @Dai I have not.  I agree the codegen is not ideal, however I find it really hard to believe it does not offer a method to pass a username and password to a SOAP service. I will try digging around a little more before trying your suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The reason why is likely because historically SOAP never really used HTTP Basic authentication - nor any HTTP features, really - SOAP just crammed everything in the SOAP Envelope (i.e. the HTTP request body), including authX (authentication and authorization) data. A common authX system was/is [WS-Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security), which used signed-requests instead of transmitting credentials in-channel.

Comment: @Dai - really appreciate your feedback.  So why when I use fiddler to trace the .net framework request I can actually see the basic auth header being added?  And why would the SOAP client generated by .net-core not do that.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning There's 1,001+ possible reasons for that - and you haven't posted enough code for me to tell you (no, this comment is not an invitation for you to dump your entire project sources online either).